# Building Applications with Force.com - Part 2 || Automating Business Processes with Approval Processes

Tags: force.com, approval-process

**LINK TO PREMIER SUPPORT HELP TUTORIAL**

(see Building Applications with Force.com - Part 2, *Lesson* : Automating Business Processes with Approval Processes)

[CLICK HERE](https://lms.cfs-api.com/v1/12/lms.aspx?hash=WUlRa1pjd0RRUDVFWDhsREd3RWQxUzhxKzlDSUdqVmtLdHVYOEw5b2RwSzltbVp0UUgxOTFjYXJ1Tk5hekJwT1dRV1lMeE9YWnE4aDhFMEVTNThaNU5OUEZkSEdDT2p1SnhqQVZmSWM4cmRMNy9lUlBlUWdsalVEUExRbmlnWEhHWnFNdTg4V215K1V6b2pLdGsvRW1oYTh4dFFOaWlnbkJpOGNjVXZWaUZzPQ==)

**LINK TO EXERCISE GUIDE**

(see "13-1: Create Multi-Step Approval Processes")

[CLICK HERE](https://lms.cfs-api.com/v1/content/42ffc01a-4c29-4d9a-9552-527fff764758/presentation_content/external_files/automatingbusinessprocesseswithapprovalprocessesexerciseguide.pdf)

**PROBLEM**

On task 7. G. from the above mentioned Exercise Guide, See : "On the Approval History related list, click Submit for Approval, " this is where things go awry.  Please read below for the error message that I receive after completing the steps prior to getting this information.

[image]

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong (as I have been trying to troubleshoot for about 50 - 60 minutes now with no luck using Google or repeating the exercise)?

Comment: The error simply says - you are trying to insert 'Pending' as a value of a picklist in which there is no available option of 'Pending'. The picklist is restricted to its own values and doesn't take any other values.

Comment: Thank you so much!   That was such an easy & quick fix.  You are the best!

Comment: Oh I doubt that but glad I could help. :)